# project merge - flutter into native ios project

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I'm doing some research regarding the integration module into a mature iOS project.
The only way I found is to write a new flutter module and integrate it into the existing app using `FlutterEngine` and `FlutterViewController`. Seems fine and it's working pretty well but one of the disadvantages of this solution is to have separate project/repo (with old native app) and another repo with flutter module with a corresponding iOS project called "Runner".

Is there any solution to merge this "Runner" project into the existing native app so that when i call `flutter run` old app is run or another solution for having only one project.

Comment: You can use the second solution from here: https://medium.com/@parserdigital/how-to-successfully-migrate-from-native-android-ios-mobile-apps-to-flutter-64a94d092c5